# Exception is not being logged/throwed inside of completable future

Tags: java

I just realised that exception inside of whenComplete, in completable future is not being logged/throwed. Can someone explain that? How to properly use whenComplete?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    var c =   CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("done");

    });

    c.whenComplete((unused, throwable) -> {

        System.out.println((5/0));


        throw new RuntimeException("I am throwing an exception");



    });

    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

output of this block of code

done
ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) (emphasis mine)

> ```
> public CompletableFuture<T> whenComplete(BiConsumer<? super T,? super Throwable> action)
> ```
>
> Description copied from interface: `CompletionStage`
>
> Returns a new `CompletionStage` with the same result or exception as this stage, that executes the given action when this stage completes.
>
> When this stage is complete, the given action is invoked with the result (or `null` if none) and the exception (or `null` if none) of this stage as arguments. The returned stage is completed when the action returns. **If the supplied action itself encounters an exception, then the returned stage exceptionally completes with this exception unless this stage also completed exceptionally.**

`whenComplete` returns a new `CompletableFuture`. `CompletableFuture` keeps track of what exception (if any) has occurred and expects you to deal with it. By ignoring the return value, you're suppressing the exception.

To wait on the result of the future, or throw if it throws, use [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--).

```
c.whenComplete((unused, throwable) -> {
  System.out.println((5/0));
  throw new RuntimeException("I am throwing an exception");
}).join();
```

Comment: If I understood correctly to avoid blocking( because .join will block thread), I can use against whenComplete, whenComplete again

            c.whenComplete((unused, throwable) -> {

                System.out.println((5 / 0));

                throw new RuntimeException("I am throwing an exception");


            }).whenComplete((unused, throwable) -> {

                if(throwable != null)
                    System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());

            });
output: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

But it looks quite unhandy

Comment: An exception can't be handled in the main thread until the asynchronous task has completed. You can't handle exceptions that literally haven't happened yet. So either `join` on the main thread or handle it in the asynchronous job. Those are your two options. Java isn't a time machine.